# Detect process death after calling startActivityForResult

Tags: android

Can I detect the fact that the activity in a 3rd party application died after I called it via startActivityForResult?

```
04-30 17:07:28.408 4223-4634/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.citrix.mail.droid (pid 26179) has died(120,858)
```

For some reason this 3rd party mail client keeps dying but only on this one phone. It used to work and works on other phones, so it is a special case.

onActivityResult is not called.

UPDATE:
The reason the onActivityResult is not called is due to activity being dead.

raw log - lots of noise
https://pastebin.com/MhFFEP7s

```
05-02 10:48:17.134 14781-14868/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ContactsProviderWorker
                                               Process: com.citrix.mail.droid, PID: 14781
                                               android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 1806): Could not open database
                                               #################################################################
                                               Error Code : 1806 (SQLITE_CANTOPEN_EACCES)
                                               Caused By : Application has no permission to open the specified database file.
                                                (unknown error (code 1806): Could not open database)
                                               #################################################################
                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:242)
                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:203)
                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:518)
                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:209)
                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:181)
                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:1156)
                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:1101)
                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:832)
                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:234)
                                                   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
                                                   at citrixSuper.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.ctx_getReadableDatabase(Unknown Source)
                                                   at citrixSuper.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase_aroundBody2(Unknown Source)
                                                   at citrixSuper.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase_aroundBody3$advice(Unknown Source)
                                                   at citrixSuper.android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.citrix.contacts.providers.af.<init>(LegacyApiSupport.java:527)
                                                   at com.citrix.contacts.providers.ContactsProvider2.x(ContactsProvider2.java:1531)
                                                   at com.citrix.contacts.providers.ContactsProvider2.a(ContactsProvider2.java:1616)
                                                   at com.citrix.contacts.providers.ContactsProvider2$2.handleMessage(ContactsProvider2.java:1492)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
05-02 10:48:17.136 4223-8123/? D/Debug: !@DumpState : SHIP
05-02 10:48:17.136 4223-8123/? D/Debug: !@DumpState : debug level:0x4f4c
05-02 10:48:17.136 4223-8123/? D/Debug: !@Dumpstate : Finally, system will skip dumpstate
05-02 10:48:17.138 4223-8123/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.citrix.mail.droid/com.citrix.email.activity.MessageCompose
05-02 10:48:17.138 4223-8123/? W/MultiScreenManagerService: moveTaskBackToDisplayIfNeeded(): The task has more than one activity
05-02 10:48:17.138 4223-8123/? D/ActivityManager: moveToFront() : reason=finishActivity adjustFocus setFocusedActivity isAttached=true TaskRecord{5c6b9ebd0 #4446 A=<my package>.stage U=0 StackId=1 sz=2}
05-02 10:48:17.141 4223-8123/? D/InputDispatcher: Focused application set to: xxxx
05-02 10:48:17.142 4223-8123/? D/InputDispatcher: Focus entered window: 14157
05-02 10:48:17.143 4223-8123/? D/ActivityTrigger: ActivityTrigger activityPauseTrigger 
05-02 10:48:17.143 14157-14157/<my package>.stage D/ViewRootImpl@3ccd12b[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
05-02 10:48:17.143 14157-14157/<my package>.stage D/ViewRootImpl@3ccd12b[MainActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true -910002176}
05-02 10:48:17.143 4223-8123/? D/GameManagerService: sem_perfomance_mode: 3
05-02 10:48:17.144 4223-8123/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity <my package>.stage/<my package>.main.MainActivity
05-02 10:48:17.144 4223-8123/? W/MultiScreenManagerService: moveTaskBackToDisplayIfNeeded(): root is not base activity
05-02 10:48:17.146 4223-8123/? D/ActivityManager: moveToFront() : reason=finishActivity adjustFocus setFocusedActivity isAttached=true TaskRecord{3f84085d0 #4326 I=com.sec.android.app.launcher/com.android.launcher3.Launcher U=0 StackId=0 sz=1}
05-02 10:48:17.146 4223-8123/? D/ActivityManager: setFocusStackUnchecked: reason=finishActivity adjustFocus setFocusedActivity focusCandidate=ActivityStack{8c48f5d0 stackId=0, 2 tasks} caller=com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.moveToFront:879 com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.moveActivityStackToFront:2040 
05-02 10:48:17.146 4223-8123/? W/MultiScreenManagerService: moveTaskBackToDisplayIfNeeded(): root activity or app is null
05-02 10:48:17.148 14157-14157/<my package>.stage V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@97c44ef nm : <my package>.stage ic=null
05-02 10:48:17.148 14157-14157/<my package>.stage I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
05-02 10:48:17.148 4223-4662/? D/InputMethodManagerService: windowGainedFocus mCurrentFocusedUserId - 0 and mSecureKeypadEnabled-false
05-02 10:48:17.150 4223-8123/? D/InputDispatcher: Focused application set to: xxxx
05-02 10:48:17.150 4223-4662/? V/InputMethodManagerService: windowGainedFocus: reason=WINDOW_FOCUS_GAIN client=android.os.BinderProxy@15d5431 inputContext=null missingMethods= attribute=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@c6f32e nm = <my package>.stage controlFlags=#105 softInputMode=#110 windowFlags=#81810100
05-02 10:48:17.150 4223-4662/? V/InputMethodManagerService: Unspecified window will hide input
05-02 10:48:17.150 4223-4662/? V/InputMethodManagerService: hideCurrentInputLocked - !shouldHideSoftInput
05-02 10:48:17.150 4223-4662/? D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=314
05-02 10:48:17.150 4223-4662/? D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=314
05-02 10:48:17.151 14157-14157/<my package>.stage D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=79
05-02 10:48:17.151 14157-14157/<my package>.stage D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=78
05-02 10:48:17.151 4223-8123/? D/InputDispatcher: Focus left window: 14157
05-02 10:48:17.151 6099-6099/? I/SKBD: SamsungKeypad onFinishInput took nanoTime: 391731
05-02 10:48:17.151 6099-6099/? I/SKBD: SamsungKeypad [IMI] onStartInput - caller packageName : <my package>.stage
05-02 10:48:17.155 14157-14157/<my package>.stage D/ViewRootImpl@3ccd12b[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can I detect the fact that the activity in a 3rd party application died after I called it via startActivityForResult?

Yes. You can detect it as long as the activity which called `startActivityForResult` is alive. If the activity itself gets killed, then you cannot detect anything.

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onactivityresult):

> **The resultCode will be RESULT_CANCELED** if the activity explicitly returned that, didn't return any result, **or crashed during its operation.**

You can easily check this code and take necessary steps.

**What if activity was force finished**

If your activity is force finished, then you can't control it since this behavior is enforced by OS. Based on the documentation:

> The system may also destroy the process containing your activity to recover memory if the activity is in the Stopped state and hasn't been used in a long time, or if the foreground activity requires more resources.

You should try to restore the activity by following the steps defined [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#saras).

Additionally, you can create a `SharedPreference` where you can store a `boolean` flag which can contain  values like:

- **false** THIRD_PARTY_APP_NOT_STARTED (Default value and reset in `onActivityResult()`)
- **true** THIRD_PARTY_APP_STARTED (Set when before calling `startActivityForResult()`)

Check this value in `onCreate()` to know if 3rd party app causes issues.

Comment: You are right. The problem lies elsewhere notably in the fact that the activity is dead. It's being killed. 

    05-02 10:48:17.138 4223-8123/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.citrix.mail.droid/com.citrix.email.activity.MessageCompose

    05-02 10:48:17.144 4223-8123/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity <My Package>.MainActivity

Comment: Looks like your `MainActivity` is also getting killed. In this case `onActivityResult()` won't be called

Comment: Yes, I know. The good question is why? OS decides to kill the process that spawned the dying process? Or the dying process decides it doesn't want to go alone? :D

Comment: Ideally it shouldn't. Can you update your question with the complete crash logs?

Comment: @Sager Sorry for late reply, I had an emergency.

Comment: @user1317422 No problem. Let me check

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work as the Activity is not recreated. It just runs through `onDestroy()` and that is it. In normal logic that also exits the app, but for the kicks I made `SplashActivity` (which is shown before `MainActivity`) not finish and it is not destroyed. So `ActivityManager` just nukes `MainActivity`, each time everytime, not the whole app. Only hack I can think of (right now) is having that backup Activity in history recreate Main and handle onBackPressed and skip it if Splash is the only Activity.

Comment: Its not recreated when you launch the app again?

Comment: Well, having to manually relaunch the app is poor user experience.

Comment: Yes. Just wanted to understand, that your Activity process is getting killed or just the activity. Activity will be restored if the process was killed. The workaround that you are planning to implement won't work if process is getting killed. Before implementing, ensure to test on several other devices

Answer (score 0):

As I realized MDX Policy called Online Session Network (which is related with Enterprise Network) makes startActivityForResult and setResult methods connections breaking. Exacly what has to happen is that Secure Hub window shows up and to destroy my activity. What I figured out is to avoid using these methods but still I wanted to use activity method onActivityResult. So what I made:

- In Activity A where onActivityResult method is located I defined own
  startActivityForResult method which catch my past setResult
  invokations (from Activity B)
- In Activity B I put setResult calling
  wherever I wanted to comunicate with Activity A
- Both activities
  extends Activity C where I put setResult definition which to create
  new intent, to include extra data like request and result codes and
  to start new activity

Unfortunetelly official support team of service provider doesn't say a word about it (even after contacting with them) but I think it should be part of documentation to let people avoid app breaking because of one policy being turned on.